# How to parse or loop this

Tags: javascript, json, loops, parsing

I have tried everything I can think of to get the data but cannot figure this out.

The data is in a structure like this:

```
[{"code":1000,"day":"Sunny","night":"Clear","icon":113,"languages":
[{"lang_name":"Arabic","lang_iso":"ar","day_text":"مشمس","night_text":"صافي"}]
 }]
```

I've tried looping, using key:value using the dot notation and bracket notation and cannot get the info.

I'm trying to get to the "languages" so I can parse them for the weather.

Comment: _I've tried looping..._ Show code please

Comment: What language? Whats your expected output?

Comment: You keep saying "I've tried" but you haven't specified *what* you've tried or *what problem* you've encountered.  Can you elaborate on the actual problem?

Comment: Use JSON.Parse before looping

Comment: *I'm trying to get to the "languages"* `obj[0].languages[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr = [{"code":1000,"day":"Sunny","night":"Clear","icon":113,"languages":
[{"lang_name":"Arabic","lang_iso":"ar","day_text":"مشمس","night_text":"صافي"}]
}]

arr.forEach(function(obj){ //loop array
  obj.languages.forEach(function(language) { //loop languages
    console.log(language); //language object
    console.log(language.lang_name); //language property
  });
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! That's the first time I've run across something like this.. again HUGE Thanks!!